# In yii2 query builder how to use in operator with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I did not find any example of yii2 query builder `yii\db\Query` using in operator with where clause. for the time being I am using it this way

```
$result = (new \yii\db\Query)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('customer c')
    ->where('c.status in (' . implode(',', [0,1]) . ')')->all();
```

But there must be a better way of doing this. Thanks in advance

Comment: write your sql query you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$result = (new \yii\db\Query)
    ->select('*')
    ->from('customer c')
    ->where(['c.status' => [0, 1]])->all();
```

In the [`yii\db\QueryInterface::where()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail) API:

> The `$condition` **specified as an array** can be in one of the following two formats:
>
> - hash format: `['column1' => value1, 'column2' => value2, ...]`
> - operator format: `[operator, operand1, operand2, ...]`
>
> ... In case when a value is an array, **an `IN` expression will be generated**.
>
> - `['id' => [1, 2, 3], 'status' => 2]` generates `(id IN (1, 2, 3)) AND (status = 2)`.